# Using a SQLAlchemy Integer field to create a timedelta object for filtering

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, timedelta

I have an object called Item. It has 2 fields: a datetime row called "created_on," and an integer row called "days."

I want to query for all objects that were created "days" many days ago.

Here's how I thought it should be done:

```
now = utcnow()
session.query(Item).filter(Item.created_on + Interval(timedelta(days=Item.days)) <= now)
```

But I'm unable to create a timedelta like this. I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: InstrumentedAttribute
```

Update:

Thanks to van, I should be using a built-in function. I'm using Mysql 5.1, so it would be `timestampadd`. My new query is this:

```
now = utcnow()
session.query(Item).filter(func.timestampadd('DAY', Item.days, Item.created_on) <= now)
```

However, the new error I'm getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''DAY', items.days, items.created_on) <= '2015-07-12 ' at line 3
```

Answer (score 6):

I do not think that `Interval` will help you there, as it would not be able to coerce into DB-specific date[time] functions. So you should probably use the platform specific date[time] functions to solve this.

If you are using *postgresql*, the code below should work (assuming `Items.days` is integer):

```
q = (session.query(Item)
     .filter(func.age(now, Item.created_on) <=
             func.make_interval(0, 0, 0, Item.days)
             )
     )
```

*See `postgres'` [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) for more information.*

Comment: And what if Item.days is a float?

Comment: @mpounsett: `secs` param is `double`. So just convert your value to seconds and pass as `secs` argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
now = utcnow()
session.query(Item).filter(Item.created_on + func.make_interval(0, 0, 0, Item.days) <= now)
```

Comment: It's always better to add some explanation to the answers. In this way also future users can understand better what is your contribute