# Remove quotes in query generated by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

This is different from [Using a SQLAlchemy Integer field to create a timedelta object for comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362484/using-a-sqlalchemy-integer-field-to-create-a-timedelta-object-for-comparison) because that thread is asking which function to use when adding time. The function was found for their version of MySQL, however, the followup edits of the user digress from their original question and do not answer this question.

I'm using MySQL. I want to use a function called timestampadd. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd Its first parameter is the unit of time that I'm adding, EG: MINUTE, HOUR, DAY.

When writing the SQLAlchemy query, I can't do something like

```
datetime_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
Item.query.filter(Item.created <= sqlalchemy.func.timestampadd(MINUTE, 1, datetime_now))
```

If I do this, I'll get an undefined error for `MINUTE`. I also tried:

```
Item.query.filter(Item.created <= sqlalchemy.func.timestampadd('MINUTE', 1, datetime_now))
```

But this will generate the timestampadd call with quotes around the unit, which causes a MySQL error. How would I remove the quotes around `MINUTE` in the generated query?

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the unit argument keyword as is use a [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct:

```
Item.query.filter(
    Item.created <= sqlalchemy.func.timestampadd(text('MINUTE'), 1, datetime_now))
```