# Timedelta based on table column value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, timedelta

I have a table with 10k rss_feed URLs which I want to parse at different times because of the frequency at which they publish. In my Feed table I have the following columns:

1. rss_url (string)
2. last_parsed_at (UTC datetime with time zone)
3. frequency (int)

I want to get all feed objects which are due to be queued based on the frequency. Frequency column is number of seconds.

I was trying to use the following query

```
rss_query=db.session.query(Feed).filter(Feed.rss_url.isnot(None)).filter(Feed.available==True).filter(Feed.last_parsed_at+timedelta(seconds=Feed.frequency)<datetime.utcnow())
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component:
>   InstrumentedAttribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a SQLAlchemy Integer field to create a timedelta object for filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362484/using-a-sqlalchemy-integer-field-to-create-a-timedelta-object-for-filtering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `timedelta` does not understand SQLAlchemy constructs; it deals with numbers in Python. In order to produce an interval SQL expression you have to use the [SQL Expression Language](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/) to produce a suitable DBMS specific construct. In case of Postgresql you can use [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

```
rss_query = db.session.query(Feed).\
    filter(Feed.rss_url.isnot(None)).\
    filter(Feed.available).\
    filter(Feed.last_parsed_at +
           func.make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Feed.frequency) <
           datetime.utcnow())
```

Unfortunately [`func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) functions do not support named arguments, so you have to pass the years, months, weeks, days, hours, and minutes explicitly.

Another option is to use some arithmetic:

```
filter(Feed.last_parsed_at +
       cast('1 second', Interval) * Feed.frequency <
       datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: Which import is required to use the function "cast"?

Comment: `from sqlalchemy import cast`